In Playwright Cucumber typescript soft assertions doesn't works as expected and does't execute the further steps
Take and expmple of a sample code
When('I should see that heading {string} is visible on Screen', async function (headingText) {
    await expect.soft(page.getByRole('heading', { name: headingText })).toBeVisible();
});

In this case it does't work if a condition fails then it terminates after failing and does't execute the next steps.

In Playwright, when you use expect.soft, it allows the test to continue even if the assertion fails. However, it's important to understand that the soft method only affects the assertion itself and not the actual Playwright commands that might be executed before the assertion. In the case of page.getByRole, if the locator does not find the specified element, it can throw an error, which would halt the test execution.
So I am assuming Playwright is unable to find this part page.getByRole('heading')
Look into this for more info
